# Is Firefox nightly good for security and privacy?

Tags: web-browser, firefox

Is Firefox Nightly a good browser to use for security and privacy reasons? Because new security and crypto technologies are implemented faster in FF Nightly, but what about 0 Day security issues? Should I switch from stable to nightly?

Comment: There are way fewer people using the nightly browser and this will make it a lot easier to track your Browser. So from a privacy point, I believe it is better to hide in the masses and go with stable.

Comment: couldn't you just user some random agent spoofer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO, it's a trade-off only you can assess. As you said, it's probable that Nightly is ahead of stable regarding new security-related technologies. However, those new features are not as tested as the features in stable, so actually they might cause more harm than benefit.

Would you risk a stable browser for a less-tested more error-prone browser just to use the latest technologies? It's up to you.

Comment: +1 for security _technologies_ not security _fixes_. Any security patches will be released for all streams at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

No. If a CVE is published for FireFox (or any browser) it will be patched on both nightly and stable (which is where you get stable versions like `60.0.1`). If anything, I would expect nightly to be less secure, as it could introduce bugs that have not yet been caught.